# First-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation $ \frac {dy}{dt} = a \frac{ (b \cdot t + c )^2} {y + d\cdot (b\cdot t + c)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know if this differential equation has a solution:

$$ \frac {dy} {dt} = a \frac{ (b \cdot t + c )^2} {y + d\cdot (b\cdot t + c)}$$

I transformed it to the form:

$$ \frac {dv} {du} = \frac{A \sqrt{u}} {v + B\sqrt{u}}$$

but I couldn't solve it. 
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: you can try a numerical method if you got values for the variables

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I would like to obtain an analytical solution if it is possible.

Comment: You surely mean $\frac {dv} {du} = \frac{A u} {v + B\sqrt{u}}$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment but i understand that the form $\frac {dv} {du} = \frac{A \sqrt{u}} {v + B\sqrt{u}}$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{a(bt+c)^2}{y+d(bt+c)}$

$(y+bdt+cd)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=a(bt+c)^2$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=y+bdt+cd$ ,

Then $y=u-bdt-cd$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{du}{dt}-bd$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dt}-bd\right)=a(bt+c)^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}-bdu=a(bt+c)^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=bdu+a(bt+c)^2$

Let $x=t+\dfrac{c}{b}$ ,

Then $u\dfrac{du}{dx}=bdu+ab^2x^2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  It is a Abel differential equation as you demonstrated. Should i follow this work (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05929)  to find the exact solution ?